# Seeking QGIS plugin to create Isopleth map

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2, software-recommendations

I'm looking for a plugin for QGIS that would allow me to create an effective isopleth map.

Does one exist?

I haven't been able to find any, only independent software that would allow this type of mapping.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what exactly you are looking to achieve. It's most certainly possible with the core tools.

Comment: I have the USGS dataset on landcover and elevation. I have now extracted contours using the core functions, as you mentioned but now I'm trying to create a classified fill, such as on a topographic map.

Comment: After polygonizing the contour lines, the standard graduated renderer should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The contour plugin may achieve what you want.

> isopleth |ˈʌɪsə(ʊ)plɛθ| noun Meteorology
>
> a line on a map connecting points having equal incidence
>     of a specified meteorological feature.
>
> ORIGIN early 20th cent.: from Greek isoplēthēs ‘equal in
>     quantity’, from Greek isos ‘equal’ + plēthos ‘multitude, quantity’.